# Nested router-outlet into mat-tab

Tags: angular, angular-router

I try to achieve something that i've simplified here :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/base-angular-12-app-o1781x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

This should be like a forum.
User can be registred for several courses, so he will see multiple tabs (tab = course).
A course can  have multiple categories, so after he selects a course (with tab) he'll have to choose a category.
When category is selected, he can see a list of threads corresponding to selected course & category.

Then there will be many other pages like see thread details, create new thread etc.

When you are on the first selected tab, you can clic on a category and see threads list.
But as soon as you change tab, category selection doesn't work. You can clic on a category and see that URL is changing, but thread list will not appear.
What's weird is that if I change tab again, I can see in console logs that only then, thread's list component is built, ngOnInit is fired as well as ngOnDestroy.

Any idea about what's happening and how to fix ?

Comment: You should use `mat-tab-nav-bar` because it's built to handle route navigation. Your StackBlitz has Angular version 12. You need to upgrade it to version 13.2+ for this to work.

Comment: My project has Angular 12 version and cannot be upgraded for now. But yes i'll go for mat-tab-nav-bar,  I would have prefered to use mat-tab-group to keep animations

Comment: I see. It is unfortunate that you can't upgrade to a newer version.